# React Typescript - Error Objects are not valid as a React child

Tags: reactjs, api, react-hooks, react-typescript

I trying to Fetch data from Random user API, but I get the following error:

*"Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {title, first, last}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead."*

Here my code so far:

```
import "./styles.css";
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { User } from "../interfaces/users";
import axios, { AxiosResponse } from "axios";
export default function App() {
  const [randomUsers, setRandomUsers] = useState<User[]>([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get<User[]>("https://randomuser.me/api/?results=20")
      .then((response: AxiosResponse) => {
        setRandomUsers(response.data.results);
      });
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Names from random user API</h1>
      <ul>
        {randomUsers.map((user, key) => (
          <li key={key}>{user.name}</li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I don't understand why I can't map **randomUsers**

Here the code [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/fetch-random-user-api-sm7d4?file=/src/App.tsx:0-675):

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are facing this error because names is an object so try this

```
<li key={key}>{user.name.first}</li>
```

Comment: Yes, you are totally right. 

How can it be that I haven't seen it?.

Many thanks!